# eloquent column selection from both tables (Primary & Foreign)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have two tables, User and Post. One User can have many posts and one post belongs to only one user.

In my User model I have a hasMany relation...

```
public function post(){
    return $this->hasmany('post');
}
```

And in my post model I have a belongsTo relation...

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('user');
}
```

Now I want to join these two tables using Eloquent with() but want specific columns from the first and second table. I know I can use the Query Builder but I don't want to.

When in the Post model I write...

```
public function getAllPosts() {
    return Post::with('user')->get();
}
```

It runs the following queries...

```
select * from `posts`
select * from `users` where `users`.`id` in (<1>, <2>)
```

But what I want is...

```
select `id`, `text AS post_text` from `posts`
select id,username from `users` where `users`.`id` in (<1>, <2>)
```

When I use...

```
Post::select('id', 'text AS post_text')->with('user:id, username')->get();
```

It returns user null.

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "post_text": "text",
    "user": null
}
```

Comment: How are the user and post tables called in the database?

Comment: I don't understand what you wanna ask.
can you please give me more details regarding your question?

Comment: names of tables in DB are users and posts.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the code to

```php
public function getAllPosts() {
    return Post::with('users:id,username')->get('id', 'text AS post_text');
}
```

Comment: same result. i tried this before posting question. but returns users null.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in the next line:

```
Post::select('id', 'text AS post_text')->with('user:id, username')->get();
```

In the select it expects an array

```
Post::select(['id', 'text AS post_text'])->with('user.id, username')->get();
```

Comment: same result. it returns same result.

Comment: Is there a post in the database, connected to a user?

Comment: yes..its working fine when called single selector. if called selection on both tables, then return relationship data as null.